# Search for a word in a string with certain criteria php

Tags: php, string, search

I have a string of five words (Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas). I need to search for a word that ends with "xas" and put it into an array, a word that begins with "M" and ends with "s" and put it into an array and so on. How would I go about doing this using PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Please, try to solve the problem, before asking us to help. You need to create an array of regular expressions and loop through the array of words, comparing them with expressions.

Answer (score 0):

you need implode to turn your string into an array

an array for each set of results

a for loop to go through the first array

and substring to check which states to add to which result array

```
$stateList='Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas';
$states=explode(' ',$stateList);

$endsInXas=array();
$beginsMendsS=array();

foreach ($states as $state){
    $length=strlen($state);
    if(substr($state,$length-3,3)=='xas')$endsInXas[]=$state;
    if((substr($state,0,1)=='M') and (substr($state,$length-1,1)=='s'))$beginsMendsS[]=$state;
}

echo "Ends in xas...";
print_r($endsInXas);

echo "<br />";

echo "Starts with M ends in s...";
print_r($beginsMendsS);
```

and I can't build my reputation so if this works mark it correct please